# Building recent LLVM and replacing the old version

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling, cmake

I have on my system llvm-3.6 but I want to use the most recent version (3.7 or newer). Because I am trying to develop a pass using CMake.

How can I replace the old one. I had installed it using "sudo apt-get install llvm" before, now I got follow the instructions on LLVM documentation(http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/docs/GettingStarted.html) but this builds the whole LLVM toolchain in a different directory. I want to be able to use the commands through terminal and be able to use CMake to develope llvm passes.

I am pretty new to Ubuntu (and LLVM) so please be specific. :)

Comment: I managed to replace the old version with llvm-3.7 but I couldn't do it with a build of mine. I added the repository from [link](http://llvm.org/apt/). First, I did `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.7 main"`, then `sudo apt-get install clang-3.7 lldb-3.7`. I don't write this as an answer because the title says "Building ...". Hence, if somebody describes how to build it properly and install it to correct directories, I will accept the answer.